# Showing validation message for repeating controls in template driven forms

Tags: angular

I have a form with a textbox and a radio button group. I need to have required validation on both.It works perfectly fine for the text field as

```
<div class="formControl" [class.error]="carName.touched && carName.errors?.required">
    <div class="formLabel">Name</div>
    <div class="formField">
      <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="car.name" #carName="ngModel" name="carName">
    </div>
    <div class="message" *ngIf="carName.touched && carName.errors?.required">Required field</div>
</div>
```

But not for a repeating radio button group

```
<div class="formControl" [class.error]="make && make.touched && make.errors?.required">
    <div class="formLabel">Make</div>
    <div class="formField">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let year of years">
      <input required type="radio" name="make" [(ngModel)]="car.make" #make="ngModel" [id]="year"
        [value]="year">
        <label [for]="year">{{year}}</label>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="message" *ngIf="make && make.touched && make.errors?.required">Required field</div>
</div>
```

Is it something related to having elements inside `ngFor` structural directive?
This just doesn't show the error message when it looses focus without selecting any value.

Answer (score 0):

With structural directives (like `*ngFor`), angular creates its own template (`ng-template`) for the code inside that block.

That means, that the template reference variable `make` is not available outside that code block. But here, if you'd put it inside `*ngFor` it would be shown repeatedly. We can overcome this by referring to the underlying formcontrol in your validation. Here I use `myForm` as the name of the form, you provide whatever name your form has:

```
<div *ngIf="myForm.form.hasError('required', 'make')">Required field</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xv7wbi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: This works but shows the message on load. How can I show this only when the control is touched